# Why is deque removing just one letter?

Tags: python

I am trying example with PYTHON deque.

```
import collections

d = collections.deque('abcdefgchc')
print 'Deque:', d
print 'Length:', len(d)
print 'Left end:', d[0]
print 'Right end:', d[-1]

d.remove('c')
print 'remove(c):', d
```

So I have three c's,how to remove all of them?

Comment: Do you understand what `deque()` is intended to do ?

Comment: Why are you using `deque` in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove all the occurrences of a character from a given string (without using `deque()` method) you may use:

```
word = 'abcdefgchc'
word = word.replace("c", "")

print word
```